# Toolbar overlaps Translucent status bar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-statusbar

In an activity I have a Toolbar, and its layout code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.aminiam.moviekade.fragment.AllReviewFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recReview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to have transparent status bar in my app and when I add `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` to the activity theme, Toolbar will overlaps status bar.

values-v21 style.xml:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
</style>

<style name="TransparentStatusBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

I tested all answers in Stackoverflow but they couldn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: AppBarLayout theme should be ` app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"` and add this to style `<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />` also add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in Top linear Layout

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Andorid studio says:  No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay').

Comment: also i added answer of you question in comment only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.aminiam.moviekade.fragment.AllReviewFragment">
```

Comment: It is weird, I had tested android:fitsSystemWindows="true" and it did not work at all. Now I reset my codes and tested again I saw that it is working.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A handy hack that worked for me was to add top padding to Toolbar element.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp" //status bar height
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:title="Home">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:fitsSystemWindows="true" from appbarlayout.

Comment: remove from appbar and put in toolbar  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"